# How can SqlDataReader fill data read in loop in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, loops

This is my code below:

```
SqlConnection SqlConnections = new SqlConnection();
SqlConnections.ConnectionString = Global.con;
SqlCommand SqlCommands = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,LinkedUserID From Users");
SqlConnections.Open();
SqlCommands.Connection = SqlConnections;
SqlDataReader SqlDataReaders =   SqlCommands.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while (SqlDataReaders.Read())
{
   //
}
SqlDataReaders.Close();
```

Im trying to run look with this code for read user id and LinkedUserID I want to all both ids for make a efface on all users as per i want please let me know how can i read both ids and return to ever single id for make a affect in database. i want to do this for use in MLM web appls during new join under any old member so i can make a affect points other user easily. any one have a idea.

Thank You

Comment: Can you please state clearly what you want to achieve? I'm getting lost in stars.

Comment: sure i want to read all id and linked user ids with user why i want to use because when any user give a new joying at that case i want to change points of other all upper user on new joining

Comment: So you can fetch it as SqlDataReaders["Id"]  and SqlDataReader["LinkedUserID"].You can write fetch code inside the while loop.

Comment: please give me example how can i do this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a class to hold the data you're fetching:

```
public class LinkData
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int LinkedUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you iterate over your `SqlDataReader`, create instances of that class and store them e.g. in a `List<LinkData>` variable:

```
List<LinkData> links = new List<LinkData>();

using (SqlConnection SqlConnections = new SqlConnection(Global.con))
using (SqlCommand SqlCommands = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,LinkedUserID From Users", SqlConnections))
{
    SqlConnections.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader SqlDataReaders = SqlCommands.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        while (SqlDataReaders.Read())
        {
            LinkData newItem = new LinkData();
            newItem.Id = SqlDataReaders.GetInt32(0);
            newItem.LinkedUserId = SqlDataReaders.GetInt32(1);

            links.Add(newItem);
        }

        SqlDataReaders.Close();
   }
```

At the end, your `Links` list should contain all data fetched from the database.

This is just the absolute "bare bones" solution - in your real-world code, you should probably also add some check to protect your code from crashing if one of the values is `NULL` in the database.

Comment: Hello marc_s,how can i count links list is and return value.

Comment: I need to use loop for Links list?

Comment: If all you want to do is to retrieve data why not use DataAdapter and DataTable to store data.

Comment: @AshishCharan: using `SqlDataReader` is still a bit faster, and using a `List<LinkData>` has a lot less overhead than a `DataSet` or a `DataTable`